# Why McNemar is usually significant even in case of zero events on both sides?

Tags: r, mcnemar-test

After propensity score matching, we can assess balance between matched cohorts using McNemar test.
I wonder why it is usually significant even in case of zero events  on both sides.
I saw [prior question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359291/sample-size-and-number-of-events-limitations-for-mcnemars-test) but this didn't answer my query. Code obtained from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exact2x2/vignettes/exactMcNemar.pdf)

`x<-matrix(c(1,1,85,85),2,2); mcnemar.test(x)`

> McNemar's Chi-squared test with
> continuity correction
> data:  x
> McNemar's chi-squared = 84.012, df =
> 1, p-value < 2.2e-16

`x<-matrix(c(0,0,86,86),2,2); mcnemar.test(x)`

> McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction
> data:  x
> McNemar's chi-squared = 80.105, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16

This is the data that I am trying to do McNemar test for it. I have many outcomes and Null hypothesis would be "No difference between both groups" while the alternative hypothesis would be that difference exists

[image]
Am I doing something wrong?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: mcnamar test is just a binomial test over the two diagonal cells of the matrix (upper right and lower left). the other ones are ignored.

Comment: @carlo So, its use here is correct and I can use it in such low events number?

Comment: dunno. if i knew I would have posted a full answer. the point anyway is what is the actual hypothesis you want to test

Comment: Always try to post the data, not just a code which creates the data. I.e., in your example, show the frequncy tables themselves.

Comment: @ttnphns Thx for your advices. I added the outcomes table and stated the null hypothesis. Upvoted your comment.

Comment: Read about what this test tests. Carlo above has actually answered you.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 86 matched pairs of values judging by your opening remarks. In that case the table you need is one which shows the diagonal as being those pairs which were both positive and those which were both negative. The off-diagonal cells are those where one pair member is positive and one negative. As it stands you are saying that there are 172 pairs, which seems to contradict the table you show and there are 96 pairs which agreed and 86 which differed, all in the same direction.

I think you have misunderstood what it going on here.